# Spring Basic: Relation between Services-repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm designing a new module and I need to know about if it is "correct" the communication between Services and Repositories corresponding to differents objects. Example: I have Object1 and Object2. Object1 is composed by many Object2. And I have this code:

```
@Repository
public class Object1Repository{}

@Repository
public class Object2Repository{}

@Service
public class Object1ServiceImpl{

private Object1Repository obj1Repo;
private Object2Repository obj2Repo;

}

@Service
public class Object2ServiceImpl{
private Object2Repository obj1Repo;
}
```

It is an acceptable practice to call from Object1Service... directly to Object2Repository? Or should I call from Object1Service to Object2Service and make all the calls to object2Repository from its corresponding Service?

Many times, while I'm manipulating object1 in my services, I need to load a certain part of an object2, and I need to know if it is a good solution to call directly to the repository.

This is a kind of thing that is not present in my books of Spring, and I don't have the enough experience to determine if it is a regular practice or I'm breaking the architecture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repositories/Data Access Objects should be reusable, it's ok to have multiple services refer to the same repository. They should also be stateless, so that multiple references to them shouldn't be 'breaking the architecture'.

If there is some business logic in a method of Object2Service that you need from Object1Service, then you should call that method, but otherwise there's nothing wrong with calling the repository directly without going through the other service.

The thing to pay attention to is where the transactional boundaries are. If both services are transactional with propagation required then this is easy, you can mix and match with no problem. If for some reason one of the services is transactional but the other isn't, and some of the repositories are transactional but others aren't, then you would need to make sure you have some kind of transactional demarcation going on and don't call a repository that doesn't specify being transactional from a service that doesn't specify being transactional.

Also, be aware that in general services don't have to map one-to-one to specific entities, it's normal for a service to span multiple domain objects. A service might correspond to a specific kind of user, where the methods implement detail-level use cases (the low-level actions that the user performs, each of which you likely want executed as a single unit of work). While repositories can be cranked out by a code generator to some extent based on the tables in the database, a service's implementation is not necessarily mechanical like that, it depends on the business logic that needs to be exposed.